# Retorno null JSP

Tags: java, html, jsp

Galera, estou com um probleminha besta mas que está me tirando do sério em um simples exercício da faculdade.

A intenção é somente fazer um programa que receba uma quantidade x e um valor y, e multiplique o mesmo. Porém, é para usar métodos do java, e também jsp..

Fiz tudo certinho, porem meus métodos não estão pegando os valores digitados no textbox, alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

> Faça um programa que receba a quantidade e o valor de três produtos no seguinte formato: 
>   quantidade1 valor1 quantidade2 valor2 quantidade3 valor3.
>   O programa deve calcular esses valores no seguinte formato:
>   TOTAL = Quantidade1* Valor1 + Quantidade2 * valor2 + Quantidade3 * Valor3.
>   Mostrar sub-total e o total geral.

Segue códigos:

**HTML:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Exercicio 1 em jsp</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>

        <form name="frm"  action="calcularSoma.jsp" method="post">
            <table border="0" align="center" bordercolor="blue">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Quantidade 1:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="txtQtd1" size="2" />  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Valor 1:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="txtVlr1" size="2" />  
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Quantidade 2:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="txtQtd2" size="2" />  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Valor 2:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="txtVlr2" size="2" />  
                    </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Quantidade 3:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="txtQtd3" size="2" />  
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <b>Valor 3:</b>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="txtVlr3" size="2" />  
                    </td>


                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                       <input type="submit" value="Calcular" name="acao"> 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="reset" value="Limpar">
                    </td>

                </tr>

            </table>
        </form> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**JSP:**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" errorPage="jspTrataErra.jsp"%>
<jsp:useBean id="objCalcularSub" class="packageJeanZika.somaTudo"/>
<jsp:setProperty name="objCalcularSub" property="*"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Exercicio</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Cálculo</h3>
        <%-- Apresentação dos dados via HTML --%>
        <pre>
           ---------- DADOS OBTIDOS DO BROWSER ---------------------
           Subtotal1 : <%=objCalcularSub.retornaValorSubTotal1()%>
           Subtotal2 : <%=objCalcularSub.retornaValorSubTotal2()%>
           Subtotal3 : <%=objCalcularSub.retornaValorSubTotal3()%>
           ---------------------------------------------------------
           Total geral: <%=objCalcularSub.retornaTotalGeral()%>
           <%-- Total Geral  <%=objSomaNum.RetTotal()%> --%>
           ---------------------------------------------------------
        </pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Java:**

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Jean Cunha
 */
package packageJeanZika;

public class somaTudo {

    private float txtVlr1 ;
    private float txtVlr2 ;
    private float txtVlr3 ;
    private int txtQtd1 ;
    private int txtQtd2 ;
    private int txtQtd3 ;

    public void setVlr1(float txtVlr1) {
        this.txtVlr1 = txtVlr1;
    }

    public void setVlr2(float txtVlr2) {
        this.txtVlr2 = txtVlr2;
    }

    public void setVlr3(float txtVlr3) {
        this.txtVlr3 = txtVlr3;
    }

    public void setQtde1(int txtQtd1) {
        this.txtQtd1 = txtQtd1;
    }

    public void setQtde2(int txtQtd2) {
        this.txtQtd2 = txtQtd2;
    }

    public void setQtde3(int txtQtd3) {
        this.txtQtd3 = txtQtd3;
    }

    public float retornaValorSubTotal1() {

        return txtQtd1 * txtVlr1;
    }

    public float retornaValorSubTotal2() {

        return txtQtd2 * txtVlr2;
    }

    public float retornaValorSubTotal3() {

        return txtQtd3 * txtVlr3;
    }

    public float retornaTotalGeral(){

        return retornaValorSubTotal1() + retornaValorSubTotal2() + retornaValorSubTotal3();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o input se chama `name="txtQtd1"`, o seu bean precisa ter um método chamado `setTxtQtd1` mas no seu código ele se chama `setQtde1`. Vi que o nome do campo na classe está correto txtQtd1, então deve ser porque você renomeou o campo e esqueceu de renomear o setter. Alguns ambientes de desenvolvimento renomeiam os getters/setters automaticamente e outros não...

Faça a mesma correção para todos os campos que tiverem nomes que não casam.

Comment: Marcus, boa tarde!  Nas mosca!! era isso mesmo, muito obrigado!! RESOLVIDO!

Comment: Que bom que resolveu :-)
Obs.: O site tem um recurso para marcar a resposta correta, uma marca de seleção (assim: ✓) ao lado da resposta.